# How to plot crystal field d orbitals

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

As the question said , i was trying to plot the crystal field orbitals using python. i know the spherical harmonics calculation can be a bit complex so this is how i tried to do it :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(233, projection='3d')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(234, projection='3d')
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(235, projection='3d')


theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

# Define the radial functions for each orbital
dx2_minus_y2 = np.sqrt(3/np.pi) * np.cos(phi)**2
dz2 = np.sqrt(5/16*np.pi) * (3*np.cos(phi)**2 - 1)
dyz = np.sqrt(15/np.pi) * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(phi) * np.exp(1j*theta)
dxz = np.sqrt(15/np.pi) * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(phi) * np.exp(1j*theta)
dxy = np.sqrt(15/np.pi) * np.sin(phi)**2 * np.exp(2j*theta)


# Convert spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates
x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

# colormap
colormap = plt.cm.viridis

# Plot the d-orbitals in separate subplots
ax1.plot_surface(x * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2), y * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2), z * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2), cmap=colormap, alpha=0.8)
ax1.set_title('d_x^2 - y^2')
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.plot_wireframe(x * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2), y * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2) , z * (dx2_minus_y2 - y**2) , color='gray', linewidth=0.1)



ax2.plot_surface(x * dz2, y * dz2, z * dz2, cmap=colormap, alpha=0.8)
ax2.set_title('d_z^2')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.plot_wireframe(x * dz2, y * dz2, z * dz2 , color='gray', linewidth=0.1)



ax3.plot_surface(x * dyz.real, y * dyz.real, z * dyz.real, cmap=colormap, alpha=0.8)
ax3.set_title('d_yz')
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.plot_wireframe(x * dyz.real, y * dyz.real, z * dyz.real , color='gray', linewidth=0.1)


ax4.plot_surface(x * dxz.real, y * dxz.real, z * dxz.real, cmap=colormap, alpha=0.8)
ax4.set_title('d_xz')
ax4.axis('off')
ax4.plot_wireframe(x * dxz.real, y * dxz.real, z * dxz.real, color='gray', linewidth=0.1)



ax5.plot_surface(x * dxy.real, y * dxy.real, z * dxy.real, cmap=colormap, alpha=0.8)
ax5.set_title('d_xy')
ax5.axis('off')
ax5.plot_wireframe(x * dxy.real, y * dxy.real, z * dxy.real, color='gray', linewidth=0.1)



fig.suptitle('Spatial Orientation of d-Orbitals with XYZ Axes', y=1.02)


plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

[image: d orbitals]

The picture above is what i got from the plot . i compared it to a picture i found online :

[image]

Is there a way to fix my code so i can get a similar figure ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to fix the aspect ratio. If you access the x, y and z limits with `ax1.get_xlim3d()`, `ax1.get_ylim3d()`, `ax1.get_zlim3d()` for example, you can see they're different. You can set the aspect ratio with `ax1.set_aspect('equal')`. Adding this line after every block of code, and changing `ax1` to `ax2`, etc., I got this plot, which looks kinda like the one you want to get.

[image]

Also, you can add LaTeX to your text if you surround it with `$`, like `ax1.set_title(r'$d_{x^2 - y^2}$')`. Don't forget to make it a raw string so some LaTeX commands aren't wrongly interpreted as escape characters.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted , thank you so much . some of the orientations are also not correct .is there a way to fix it ? Is there a way to also add a the xyz axes in the plot like shown in the picture i found online above ?

Comment: That's quite annoying to do. You have to use `ax1.view_init(azim=..., elev=..., roll=..., vertical_axis=...)`, and iterate until you find an appropriate setting. It's quite tedious. The axes you can add by using plot commands. `ax1.plot(xs=[-0, 0], ys=[-0, 0], zs=[-1, 1], c='red', zorder=1000)` adds the z axis. I changed the colors to `red`, `green`, `blue` to differentiate them and `zorder` to put them above the drawings. That did reveal your x2-y2 plot has the z axis going through the lobes... I don't know much about this, but that's not correct, right? Z2 was right though.